# how to hide html button when disabled

Tags: javascript, css

GOOD MORNING, I'm editing on this code... someone can solve this: how to hide the button when it is disabled?

```js
function Selected() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
}

function onChange() {
  console.log(Selected());
  document.getElementById('scoreButton').disabled = Selected() < 1;
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
});
```

```html
<div class="q">
<dl id="1">
    <dd><b>TEXT.</b><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1a"> 1. </label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1b"> 2. </label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1c"> 3. </label>
    <hr></dd>
 </dl>

<div><input type="button" value="BUTTON" disabled="" id="scoreButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When the page is started in JS get the element by id and set the class to hidden

Comment: You have to show us what you tried to "hide the button when it is disabled".

Comment: I'm trying to add this to the code....  
 document.getElementById('scoreButton').style.display = "none";

Answer (score 1):

Using simple CSS:

```
button[disabled] { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Selected() {
  return document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]:checked').length;
  
}

function onChange() {
  console.log(Selected());
  document.getElementById('scoreButton').disabled = Selected() < 1;
 
}

document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(node => {
  node.addEventListener('change', onChange, false);
  
});
```

```css
:disabled {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="q">
<dl id="1">
    <dd><b>1. text.</b><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1a"> 1. </label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1b"> 2. </label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1c"> 3. </label>
    <hr></dd>
  


<div><input type="button" value="BUTTON" disabled="" id="scoreButton"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: :disabled {
  display:none;
}